# Pandas read_excel percentages as strings

Tags: python, pandas

My excel sheet has a column of percentages stored with the percent symbol (eg "50%"). How can I coerce `pandas.read_excel` to read the string "50%" instead of casting it to a float?

Currently the `read_excel` implementation parses the percentage into the float 0.5. Additionally if I add a `converter = {col_with_percentage: str}` argument, it parses it into the string '0.5'. Is there a way to read the raw percentage value ("50%")?

Comment: No, because internally Excel stores that as a number. It is just formatted that way. You can multiply by 100, add a percentage sign after reading the file.

Answer (score 9):

You can pass your own function with the converters.  Something to make a string (eg: 50%) could look like:

#### Code:

```
def convert_to_percent_string(value):
    return '{}%'.format(value * 100)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', converters={
    'percents': convert_to_percent_string})
print(df)
```

#### Or as a lambda:

```
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', converters={
    'percents': lambda value: '{}%'.format(value * 100)})
```

#### Results:

```
  percents
0    40.0%
1    50.0%
2    60.0%
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate string after reading

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.ranf(size=(4,1)),columns =['col_with_percentage'])
df['col_with_percentage_s']= (df.col_with_percentage*100).astype(int).astype(str)+'%'
df
```

Output:

```py
    col_with_percentage col_with_percentage_s
0   0.5339712650806299  53%
1   0.9220323933894158  92%
2   0.11156261877930995 11%
3   0.18864363985224808 18%
```

But better way is to format on display, you can do it by [style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) in pandas

```py
df.style.format({'col_with_percentage': "{:.0%}"})
```

Output:

```py
col_with_percentage col_with_percentage_s
0   53% 53%
1   92% 92%
2   11% 11%
3   19% 18%
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I write a special conversion because sometimes in Excel, it is possible these percentages are melted with true strings or numbers in the same columns, and sometimes with or without decimal.

Examples :

"12%", "12 %", "Near 20%", "15.5", "15,5%", "11", "14.05%", "14.05", "0%"; "100%", "no result", "100"

And I want keep the percentage symbol from true Excel percentage values, keeping
decimals, without change the other values:

```
import re
df[field] = (df[field].apply(lambda x: str(round(float(x) * 100, 2)).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') + ' %' if re.search(r'^0\.\d+$|^0$|^1$',x) else x))
```

It works, but remains one problem: if a cell contains a true number between 0 and 1, so it becomes a percentage:

"0.3" becomes "30%"

But this is a special case, when the Excel file is wrong builded, revealing a true error. So I just add special alerts to manage this special cases.