# How to read a particular sheet in an .XLSX file in Python by reading a column as a String without converting it to float

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I have two sheets in the XLSX file. I want to read data only from sheet 2 into a dataframe. I have two columns as shown. Column 'Target' has percent values. However some of the values are of "Percentage" format (Have % sign) and others are "General" (Do not have % sign). I want to read this column in a Pandas DataFrame as a string so that I can append a '%' sign at the end of values which do not have a percent sign.
[Sample Input XLSX file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNO6b.png)

I tried the following:

1. read_excel: I specified the sheet name but it is converting the "Target" column into a float datatype. So 10.75% is getting converted into 0.1075 in Python.
2. read_csv: This does not let me specify the particular sheet name.

My final dataframe should have that "Target" column with values as is and with a % symbol without converting them to a float
Any help is appreciated.

I have tried with dtype=str and dtype={'Target'=str} as parameters, but none of them worked.

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977649/pandas-read-excel-percentages-as-strings ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read\_excel percentages as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977649/pandas-read-excel-percentages-as-strings)